# web.config and membership

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, hosting

I have an Runtime error when I'm trying to perform login action or create user action on published website.

I have an ASPNETDB.MDF in appData folder, that created from ASP.NET Configuration. 
I created new database in hosting, exported from ASPNETDB.MDF to a new database. I changed connection string.
Localy it work perfect, even with new connection string, but after i publish it i have an Runtime error.

I'm using asp login control and CreateUserWizard. 
BTW, i've created some GridView and SqlDataSource to show all users, and it works.. But login and createWizard are not.

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=mssql3322.dotnet-host.com;Database=aspnetdb3;Uid=SomeUserNAme;Password=SomePassword;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>  
  </connectionStrings>
   <system.web>    
      <roleManager enabled="true" />
      <authentication mode="Forms" />
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />     
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

BTW, i tryed to add membership provider to web.config and it didn't work even localy ))

**UPD:**

The error
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Can you give us more information about it just not working? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I added the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starters you could add the following to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This should allow you to get a more detailed error message about what is wrong. See if that get's you started down the right path. It should at least provide more information about what might be wrong.

**Update** - try this in your web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Server=mssql3322.dotnet-host.com;Database=aspnetdb3;Uid=SomeUserNAme;Password=SomePassword;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=mssql3322.dotnet-host.com;Database=aspnetdb3;Uid=SomeUserNAme;Password=SomePassword;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Update** - That worked! Here is a short explanation why:
By default the ASP membership classes use the connection string *LocalSqlServer*. The reason the code worked on your local machine is because the connection *LocalSqlServer* is defined in a machine level config file to point to the local sql database. When you published it the SqlDataSource/GridView worked because it was pulling the connection named *ConnectionString* that pointed to the correct server. However ASP membership was still trying to connect to the *LocalSqlServer* connection. The above config just ignores the machine level *LocalSqlServer* connection and defines it's own (and it leaves the *ConnectionString* one in place so that the GridView continues to function).

Comment: I updated.. The error is :
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: @RaShe That is a message that the database cannot be reached. Did you change all source code that used the old `connectionstring` to the new one? Re-check it again, maybe the Membership, Roles and Authentication are still pointing to an unexisting or missing connection string.

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with your connection string maybe. You said that you have a working SqlDataSource/GridView. Is that SqlDataSource using the exact same connection string? (My first guess would be that there is something wrong with either the "Server=" part of the connection string or the name in the <connectionStrings> tag is wrong)

Comment: Try this real quick: change the connection string name from "ConnectionString" to "LocalSqlServer".  By default the role provider is looking for this as the default connection string name.

Comment: @balexandre I checked, the problem is that i can't check the connection string got login asp control.

Comment: @EverPresent SqlDataSource/GridView useing exact the same connectionn string.
The change to  "LocalSqlServer" give me an error: 
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The entry 'LocalSqlServer' has already been added.
and even the GridView doesn't work..

Comment: Ok, I think we're on the right track though.  Try the connection string section that I updated in the post above.

Comment: @EverPresent the next error is:
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Comment: Great! That at least means we have the database connection working now! Can you mark this question as answered and start that as a new question? This thread is getting very long and the next problem might take a little more time to work through.

Comment: @EverPresent thanks, I'll try to find the answer myself first )

Comment: No problem! If you post that as a question put a link to it here and I'll try to follow it and put my two cents in!